# Unable to cast object of generic type to generic interface C#

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I have two interfaces:

```
public interface IDbModel {}
public interface IDmModel {}
```

And classes derived from this:

```
public class DbModel : IDbModel {}
public class DmModel : IDmModel {}
public class Middle { }
```

Also I have two interfaces with restrictions:

```
public interface IRule { }
public interface IRule<in TInput, out TOutput> : IRule
    where TInput : IDmModel
    where TOutput : IDbModel
{
    TOutput Apply(TInput elem);
}
```

And one abstract class derived from this interface:

```
public abstract class Rule<TDmModel, TMiddle, TDb> : IRule<TDmModel, TDb>
    where TDmModel : IDmModel
    where TDb : IDbModel
{
    private readonly Func<TDmModel, TMiddle> _rule;
    protected Rule(Func<TDmModel, TMiddle> rule) { _rule = rule; }
    protected abstract TDb Apply(TMiddle transformedMessage);
    public TDb Apply(TDmModel elem) { ... }
}
```

After this I created two classes derived from this abstract class:

```
public class RuleA : Rule<DmModel, Middle, DbModel>
{
    public RuleA(Func<DmModel, Middle> rule) : base(rule) {}
    protected override DbMode Apply(Middle transformedMessage) { ... }
}

public class RuleB : RuleA
{
    public RuleB() : base((dm) => new Middle()) {}
}
```

> RuleB : RuleA : Rule< DmModel,Middle,DbModel > : IRule< IDmModel,IDbModel > : IRule

And when I try to cast object of `RuleB` to `IRule<IDmModel, IDbModel>` occours unhandled exception

> Unable to cast object of type 'ParsreCombinators.RuleB' to type 'ParsreCombinators.IRule`2[ParsreCombinators.IDmModel,ParsreCombinators.IDbModel]'.

```
var ruleB = (IRule<IDmModel, IDbModel>)new RuleB(); // Exception 
IDbModel dbModel = ruleB.Apply(new DmModel());
```

What wrong with [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0dgA60)

To make the example less confusing I simplify it:

**EDIT:**

After the answers I understood, what is the problem and to make the example less confusing I simplify it:

```
public interface IDbModel {}
public interface IDmModel {}

public class DbModel : IDbModel {}
public class DmModel : IDmModel {}

public interface IRule<in TInput, out TOutput>
    where TInput : IDmModel
    where TOutput : IDbModel
{
    TOutput Apply(TInput elem);
}

public class RuleA : IRule<DmModel, DbModel>
{
    public DbModel Apply(DmModel elem) { ... }
}

var ruleA = (IRule<IDmModel, IDbModel>)new RuleA(); // Exception
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's a lot of levels of indirection you got there...

Here's the issue:

```
public abstract class Rule<TDmModel, TMiddle, TDb> : IRule<TDmModel, TDb>
    where TDmModel : IDmModel
    where TDb : IDbModel

public class RuleA : Rule<DmModel, Middle, DbMode>
public class RuleB : RuleA
...
var ruleB = (IRule<IDmModel, IDbModel>)new RuleB();
```

RuleB implements IRule<DmModel, DbMode>

This cannot be cast to IRule<IDmModel, IDbModel>.  C# does not support this type of casting.  For the same reason, you cannot do `List<object> b = (List<object>)new List<string>();`  (Gives "Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string> to System.Collections.Generic.List<object>.")

This is an issue with covariance.

Here is some more information from Microsoft on the subject: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance

Comment: @kogoia I did a little more digging, and noticed that you declared your interface parameters as `in` and `out` respectively.  This means that you actually CAN do this: `var ruleB = (IRule<DmModel, IDbModel>)new RuleB();`  DmModel must be concrete in this case, but IDbModel can be left as an interface in the cast.  Does that help at all with what you're trying to do?

Comment: Not quite, I would like to get such a result as above `(IRule<IDmModel, IDbModel>)new RuleB()`

Comment: `public RuleB() : base((dm) => new Middle()) {}` I want that `dm` was `DmModel` in here `(dm) => new Middle(dm.SomeProperty)`, `SomeProperti` is property of DmModel class which isn't in interface declaration and can't be

Comment: Well, you could try declaring both interface parameters as `out`.  I don't understand what you're doing well enough to know if that will work or not.

Answer (score 4):

This is a pretty confusing example, but I believe the problem is you're casting to a generic type and giving it interfaces, when the classes your deriving from are forcing you to use DmModel and DbMode.

Perhaps this is what you meant:

```
var ruleB = (IRule<DmModel, DbMode>)new RuleB();
```

That compiles just fine, and I with that way your classes are structured, is the only option other than restructuring.

Comment: Yes it compiles and works, but I don't know type of this classes when I do casting. I mean `DmModel` and `DbModel`

Comment: The OP's problem wasn't compiling, but a runtime exception. However, this suggestion does seem to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Your interface `IRule<in TInput, out TOutput>` is both covariant *and* contravariant, which means you can't covariantly cast it.  The contravariance prevents this.

Basically, your assignment `var dbModel = (IRule<IDmModel, IDbModel>)new RuleB();` asserts that dbModel must accept *any* `IDmModel` parameter.  Unfortunately, this is not true; instances must be assignable to `DmModel` due to the concrete form of `RuleA`, so other derivatives of `IDmModel` would fail.

Comment: This is a good explanation of WHY this type of casting is not allowed.